# Eclipse: Not succeeding importing classes from another project

Tags: java, eclipse, import, classnotfoundexception

I wanted to use classes from another project, so I went on **project** -> **properties** -> **Java Bulid path** -> **projects** and **add**ed the project the classes are on. Eclipse recognized it, since it started to show the `import` option from those classes at the "warning" icon. But I'm still getting the erros `NoClassDefFoundError` and `ClassNotFoundException` from one of those classes, at the following message:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/caelum/jdbc/modelo/Contato
    br.com.caelum.servlet.AdicionaContatoServlet.service(AdicionaContatoServlet.java:50)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
root cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.caelum.jdbc.modelo.Contato
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1305)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1157)
    br.com.caelum.servlet.AdicionaContatoServlet.service(AdicionaContatoServlet.java:50)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

It's not complaining about other class that I use from the other mentioned project, the problem seems to be only at the class `Contato` that I instantiate at the line 50 of `AdicionaContatoServlet`.

Answer (score 0):

It means the class AdicionaContatoServlet requires the class com.caelum.jdbc.modelo.Contato.

You have to search for the class com.caelum.jdbc.modelo.Contato, you can Google it, and then add it to your workspace.

I am not sure if this one will work for yours or not, you can try it https://github.com/dronan/fj21-jdbc/blob/master/src/br/com/caelum/jdbc/modelo/Contato.java.

If only Contato.java does not work, you may need to download all the source code from the project above and add it to your workspace as another project.

At last, you may need to change the package name for the above project by removing "br." and you will get exact the same missing package name and class. :)

Comment: I already did the class com.caelum.jdbc.modelo.Contato, It's pretty ready. The problem is: it's at another project, and I'm trying to import it to the current project : )

Comment: That's good, so there are 3 ways to achieve this. 1. export com.caelum.jdbc.modelo.Contato and its related files as a jar file and import to your current project. 2. Right click on your workspace and import project form existing source code, you will get required project on your workspace.  3. create a new project in your current workspace and name the package as com.caelum.jdbc.modelo  and copy everything to the right place and make your project point to it. :)